# Upgrading angular 1 to 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-module, ng-upgrade

I'm trying to follow the upgrade steps for Angular 1 to 2. I've put in the following code to allow for a hybrid application:

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import {upgradeAdapter} from './upgrade-adapter';
angular.module('app', []);
angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['app'], {strictDi: true});
```

But I'm just getting the following error message in the browser console:

```
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
Line: import * as angular from 'angular';
```

Comment: Which version of angular 2 you are targeting? are you targeting the released version or some RC?

Comment: v2.0.0-alpha.34

Comment: Well, already released version is out why are you upgrading to alpha?there are so many changes between alpha to beta to RC and to final version. so if you are upgrading I would recommend to upgrade to released version directly.

Comment: I've now switched over to the released version. Still seeing the same error.